# Is it wise to store background process status updates in a file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, background-process

I'm working on a ruby gem that parses a large number of records. This gem will be used by different frontends one of them being a console ruby script, and another being a rails app that will launch it as a background job.

I'm looking for a way to let the frontends know about the status of the job with a message telling the completed percentage and the name of the operation. For example:

```
5% Initializing...
```

I know that delayed_job can take advantage of a gem called progress_job, that will store the progress in activerecord and sidekiq has similar functionality using redis, but this will force my rails app to a specific background job backend, and also won't work for non rails apps.

I was thinking about using a file (maybe json) to store the progress updates, but writing to a file for hundreds times a second for half a hour doesn't seem to be a good practice.

Is there a better way to notify the frontend about progress updates?

**UPDATE:**

After reading the comments I think that I don't need to update the status so often. Once every 5/6 seconds looks like a good idea.

Comment: You could use websockets to communicate from the backend directly to the frontend.

Comment: Any reason to not store this information in the database? Furthermore since a frontend is usually slow and doesn't update more that 2-3 times a second, why do you want to store progress updates hundreds of times a second?

Comment: "...writing to a file for hundreds times a second for half a hour..." That sounds like a bad idea, but are you sure you need to write that often? A human user certainly doesn't need that much granularity. If your job takes half an hour to run, then on average each 1% increment will take 18 seconds. With a job that long the user isn't going to sit there staring at it; they only need occasional updates to be reassured that it hasn't stalled.

Comment: @spickermann, the gem is just returning an object so the non rails frontends won't even have a databse connected. Yes, I don't need to update so often, but I was planning to update the status at the end of every line parsed since some lines will just require milliseconds, while other will take 4/5 seconds. Updating for example every 20 lines can sometimes take very long.

Comment: @TopperH Don't update every 20 lines, update every X seconds. After each line, check how much time has elapsed since the last update. If it's more than X, write an update; otherwise don't.

Comment: @Jordan,: if I can have my app to update the status every 5/6 seconds, would it be a good idea to store the update in a file? If so, would json be a good idea?

Comment: I really think you should use websockets here to communicate to the frontend.  If you have different types of frontends (like the console), you could use the Observable pattern to send those updates.  No reason to store this in a file or in the database at all.  If the percent changes, you can notify your observers (which could write to stdout for the console observer and could send a websocket to a JS frontend).

Comment: It's not a bad idea. To say whether or not it's the best solution would require more information. If you go this route JSON sounds good.

Comment: Websockets seems like overkill to me. If you're only getting updates every few seconds then polling is cheap and dead easy. @EricTerry's other points are good, though. Consider having a common interface for both front-ends (similarly to how Rails 4's ActiveJob provides a common interface for different job queues), and also consider using stdout for the console app.

Comment: Storing data like that in a file does not feel right to me: Some platforms (like Heroku) do not allow to write files, you cannot easily scale your app to multiple servers anymore (what might be a good idea not only when you have lots of traffic but also to increase uptime and reliability). Furthermore you have to ensure that the files get deleted even when the process crashes, otherwise you may run out of disk space. Storing in the app's database is easier and way more convenient.

Comment: It looks like both solutions have valid points. I'm going to investigate pros and cons of both and make a decision.

Comment: @spickermann, your point is valid. Even if all our apps are using docker containers, using a file will break portability if we someday decide to move to something like heroku. Anyway the generated file will not be to be persistent and reading the Heroku docs it seems to me that writing to "#{Rails.root}/tmp" is safe, at least until the next deploy, that being much more persistent than websockets.

Comment: @Jordan, if you want to answer with the suggestion to "update every x seconds and then use a file for storing progress" I will accept your answer.

Comment: @TopperH I've posted an answer that takes into consideration some of the good points made above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing an update every 20 lines, write an update every *N* seconds. After every line, check how much time has elapsed since the last update; if it's greater than *N*, write an update. If your job runs for 30 minutes, then each 1% increase will take, on average, 18 seconds, so there's probably no need to update the user many times per second.

Since you're going to have two or more output channels—terminal, web—that behave very differently I suggest writing a common interface that each can implement. This way the code that processes the data can just call e.g. `output_obj.write` without caring what `output_obj` is.

For your terminal program I suggest looking at how other Unixy command-line tools behave with regard to output. At their most basic they write output to `$stdout`. Most also accept a filename argument. Some will write status or progress information to `$stderr` while writing data to `$stdout`, allowing users to do something like `tool in.txt > out.txt` and still see progress information while redirecting the data output to a file (or piping it to another tool).

JSON makes sense as a serialization format if your data has any structure to it. If your output is very simple you might consider just printing it in a tabular format, setting `$,` to `ENV['OFS']` (output field separator) or, in its absence, some sane default:

```
#/usr/bin/env ruby
$, = ENV['OFS'] || "\t"

print 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
```

Then:

```
$ ruby tool.rb
foo     bar     baz

$ export OFS=';'
$ ruby tool.rb
foo;bar;baz
```

When in doubt, go with established conventions. Be boring with your output; never clever.

For your web front-end it makes less sense to write your updates to the filesystem. Use ActiveRecord or Redis or whatever your app is already using. Then have the browser poll for updates or use websockets or whatever. Do whatever's easiest; optimize/streamline later as the need arises.

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned redis in your question. Why not store progress there, unless you don't want to add any more dependencies? It has some useful feature for your case like expiration time. If you don't want to use redis, I would agree with spikerman, that storing progress in database is good solution. Basicly, writing in a file is just the same as writing in database, but more messy. Maybe I did not understand your question well, but how will you handle multiple parallel jobs? Each will create it's own file? Or there will be single file for all jobs? Is it even possible case? And websockets look like overkill to me.

Comment: I mentioned redis, since I know that there are some sidekiq plugins that relay on that. Anyway I would like to keep my gem as portable as possible and (for a frontend that is not already using sidekiq) it would be an overkill to require redis just to get updates on a process. Storing it in activerecord is not an option, since the gem will not be used only by rails applications, but also by a ruby script that doesn't even have a database.

Comment: Indeed, if want to keep it as simple is possible, then files are viable solution.